# making http2 ajax call from angular/javascript application

Tags: javascript, ajax, jetty, http2

I'm trying to make http2 implementation of my service. I used Jetty 9 with ALPN jar and I made the code as per the documentations. The server got started and I can access the url http://localhost:8443/myurl  from chrome version 51. I'm using a chrome extension HTTP2/ SPDY Indicator to see the HTTP2 request and it indicate the request is http2. When I tried to make call a service using Ajax through angularjs I can't see the extension report that HTTP2 call is made.

Is it the problem with the extension to unable to detect Ajax call. Or do I manually need to set any HTTP2 specific headers for http2 call to get activated.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome HTTP/2 Indicator extension reports whether the top level document has been downloaded using HTTP/2.

XHR calls are not reported by that extension.

If you browse chrome://net-internals/#http2 in your Chrome browser, you will see the HTTP/2 connections that are alive, and click on the one for your domain will give additional information, included XHR calls.

Alternatively, you can enable the server-side DEBUG logging for HTTP/2 by enabling the `org.eclipse.jetty.http2` category to DEBUG, and you will see the XHR calls arriving to the server.

You don't need to do anything special or add any HTTP/2 headers on your XHR calls (or those that Angular makes for you): the browser knows if it can use HTTP/2, and if it can it will use it.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I have tried from angular js application from Chrome https://localhost:8443/myurl , Url is working fine with http2 support. I have created the cordova project for ios and installed on an ipad using ios version 9.3, I am getting below exception at jetty server side.Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
        at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.server.ALPNServerConnection.select(ALPNServerConnection.java:87) ~[jetty-alpn-server-9.3.8.v20160314.jar!/:9.3.8.v20160314]
        at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:805) ~[na:1.8.0_91]

Comment: Difficult to say what you're doing... you probably have a wrong server configuration, or the client you are using does not offer strong enough TLS ciphers as required by HTTP/2.